# Possible to use wrap_content to dictate size of a view based on views that are constrained within?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Assuming we have a textview 'overlayed' on a container view, by setting the textview's constraints as below, is it possible to have the container view wrap_content in a similar way to how view groups wrap their children?

I understand that ContrainstLayout is a flat layout although I'm curious if there's a straightforward way to achieve this that I'm missing.

This is for a custom view so as a workaround around I'm currently manually setting the width of the container to the measured width of the textview, which feels rather dirty -

```
post {
        val lp = layoutParams
        if (lp.width == WRAP_CONTENT) {
                lp.width = title_txt.measuredWidth 
                layoutParams = lp
            }
        }
```

Tried various combinations of 0dp / wrap_content / constrained_width="true" etc

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="test1"
          android:textSize="28dp"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/container"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv2"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/container"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/container"
/>

<TextView
          android:id="@+id/tv2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="test2"
          android:textSize="28dp"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv1"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/container"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/container"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/container"
/>
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <View
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:text="test1"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:text="test2"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv1" />
```

[image: Result]